# Laravel 5.6 eloquent whereDate and WhereRaw error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to find all records created today and start with a 1 for the column **`functional_id`**.

I get the below syntax error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE functional_id LIKE "1%"' at line 1 (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `image_requests` where date(`created_at`) = 2019-01-24 00:00:00 and WHERE functional_id LIKE "1%")

My eloquent code:

```
$counter = ImageRequest::whereDate('created_at', $date)->whereRaw('WHERE functional_id LIKE "1%"')->count();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
$counter = ImageRequest::whereDate('created_at', $date)
    ->where('functional_id', 'like', '1%')
    ->count();
```

I think the issue is with the extra `"`. However, there's no need to use a `whereRaw()` in this case. A `where()` is more than enough and less proned for errors like this one :)

**Edit:** Based on your comment, if you want to check if the twelfth character is a `1`, the following should work:

```
$counter = ImageRequest::whereDate('created_at', $date)
    ->whereRaw('SUBSTRING(funtional_id, 12, 1) = 1')
    ->count();
```

Comment: hey thank you but I forget something I need to check if the twelvth character is a 1 because there is a date in front of it like this 2019-24-01-10000 I need to check the 1 after the date

Comment: You need to check if the twelfth character is a one?

Comment: Yes, awesome :)